# Why does this program involving a generic interface method compile?

Tags: java, generics, interface, classcastexception

The following code throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime, and the line `public String foo() { return "bar"; }` generates a warning "found 'java.lang.String', required 'T'". I understand the `ClassCastException` (the interface method is called with `T` equal to `Integer` yet `foo` returns a `String`) and I understand the warning (it's trying to warn us about exactly this problem). But what I don't understand is why the program compiles at all. Why is a method returning a `String` allowed to override a method returning a `T`?

```
public class Main {

    interface MyInterface {

        <T> T foo();
    }

    static class MyClass implements MyInterface {

        @Override
        public String foo() { return "bar"; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = ((MyInterface) new MyClass()).<Integer>foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a surprisingly deep question. The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

An instance method `mC` declared in or inherited by class `C`, overrides from `C` another method `mA` declared in class `A`, iff all of the following are true:

- The signature of `mC` is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `mA`.
- ...

[and](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods or constructors, `M` and `N`, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of `N` to the the type parameters of `M`, the same formal parameter types.

This is clearly not true in our case, as `MyInterface.foo` declares a type parameter, but `MyClass.foo` does not.

> The signature of a method `m1` is a subsignature of the signature of a method `m2` if either:
>
> - `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
> - the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of `m2`.

The spec explains the need for that second condition as follows:

> The notion of subsignature is designed to express a relationship between two methods whose signatures are not identical, but in which one may override the other. Specifically, it allows a method whose signature does not use generic types to override any generified version of that method. This is important so that library designers may freely generify methods independently of clients that define subclasses or subinterfaces of the library.

and indeed, that second condition is met in our case, as `MyClass.foo` has the signature `foo()`, which also is the erasure of the signature of `MyInterface.foo`.

That leaves the matter of the different return type. The spec [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> If a method declaration `d1` with return type `R1` overrides or hides the declaration of another method `d2` with return type `R2`, then `d1` must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for `d2`, or a compile-time error occurs.

[and](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5):

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2 iff any of the following is true:
>
> - ...
> - If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
>   - R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), is a subtype of R2.
>   - R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9).
>   - d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.

In our case, R1 = String and R2 = T. The first condition is therefore false, as String is not a subtype of T. However, String may be converted to T by unchecked conversion, making the second condition true.

The spec explains the need for the second and third conditions as follows:

> An unchecked conversion is allowed in the definition, despite being unsound, as a special allowance to allow smooth migration from non-generic to generic code. If an unchecked conversion is used to determine that R1 is return-type-substitutable for R2, then R1 is necessarily not a subtype of R2 and the rules for overriding (§8.4.8.3, §9.4.1) will require a compile-time unchecked warning.

That is, your code is accepted by the compiler because you inadvertently use two compiler features introduced to ease transition to generics by permitting a step by step generification of existing code. These features open a loop hole in the compile time type system, which may cause heap pollution and weird ClassCastExceptions in lines that may not even feature a cast in the source code. To alert you to this danger, the compiler is required to emit an unchecked warning. These features should therefore only be used for their intended purpose (compatiblity with non-generic legacy code), and otherwise avoided.

Answer (score 4):

When naively declaring `<T> T foo();` the compiler will try to infer the result type of `foo` from the variable where it will be assigned. This is the reason why this compiles. It can be easily tested:

```
interface MyInterface {
    <T> T foo();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String foo() { return "bar"; }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
        //the result of foo will be String
        String bar = myInterface.foo();
        System.out.println(bar); //prints "bar"
        try {
            //the result of foo at compile time will be Integer
            Integer fail = myInterface.foo();
            System.out.println(fail); //won't be executed
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            //for test purposes only. Exceptions should be managed better
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); //prints "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"
        }
    }
}
```

And the result at compile time cannot be `Object`. If it were object, then you would have to add a manual type cast, which is not the case.

In short, declaring a method like that is useless and can only bring confusion and chaos to the programmers.

This method declaration becomes useful in one of these cases:

- When declaring the generic `<T>` at top level of the interface/class:

  ```
  interface MyInterface<T> {
      T foo();
  }

  class MyClass implements MyInterface<String> {
      @Override
      //can only return String here. Compiler can check this
      public String foo() { return "bar"; }
  }
  ```
- When passing `Class<T>` as argument, which enables the compiler to infer the result type and raise a proper compiler error when this condition is not met:

  ```
  interface MyInterface {
      <T> T foo(Class<T> clazz);
  }

  class MyClass implements MyInterface {
      @Override
      public <T> T foo(Class<T> clazz) {
          try {
              return clazz.newInstance();
          } catch (InstantiationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace(System.out);
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
              e.printStackTrace(System.out);
          }
          return null;
      }
  }

  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          MyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
          //uncomment line below to see the compiler error
          //Integer bar = myInterface.foo(String.class);

          //line below compiles and runs with no problem
          String bar = myInterface.foo(String.class);
          System.out.println(bar);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I agree it is confusing using `<T> T` for methods, but for deserialization (where we know what we should get) that is quite useful. I assumed something like that what motivated the question.

Comment: @GáborBakos I'm not against `<T> T` but against `<T> T foo();`. A method like that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yeah, I agree those are quite confusing. For an extra check I always prefer a `Class<T>` parameter and use that to check the casting (at least the non-erased part). (Hmm. Should that parameter better be `Class<? extends T>`, or that does not make sense?)

Comment: @GáborBakos that depends on the design and your requirements. In the cases I needed to use this approach, I didn't have the need to use `Class<? extends T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because declaring a method `<T> T foo()` is essentially identical to declaring it `Object foo()`. If you had some other connection to the type parameter somewhere (perhaps the interface was parameterized on `T` and the method was just `T foo()`), then there would be some sort of link that might be violated. In this case, however, you're just falling back to the standard rule that an override can return any more specific subtype of the supertype's return.

Comment: Not only that. When naively declaring `<T> T foo();` the compiler will try to infer the result type of `foo` from the variable where it will be assigned. This becomes useful when declaring the generic at top level of the interface/class or when passing `Class<T>` as argument, when now the compiler can infer the result type and raise a proper compiler error when this condition is not met.

Comment: Hm ... and why is String more specific than T? As T is provided by the caller, it could stand for any reference type, for instance Integer, which String is not a subtype of.

Comment: @meriton Try specifying `<Integer>foo()` and assigning it to an `String`. Just `foo()` works because of type inference. This is the same way that `Collections.empty*()` works.

Comment: Why should I try that? I know what type inference is, thank you very much. I asked why you consider String to be more specific (i.e. a subtype of T), even though the type argument (specified or inferred) for T may be Integer, which String is not a subtype of?

Answer (score 0):

Because of type erasure the `T` part is just an `Object` in the byte code. You can return more specific type, in this case `String`.

Comment: @chrylis and Gabor Bakos I assumed that was the answer, but I think I lack some fundamental understanding of how the process works. This is probably a really stupid question, but if generics are just a compile time feature and are erased at runtime, why is it that these sort of errors don't stop a program actually compiling?

Comment: Generics improved type safety. In this case it already provides a warning. Usually there are switches to convert warnings to errors, which would cause stop compiling. But generics are not a silver-bullet, some things cannot be expressed with it, in this case you can override it with casting for example (here type erasure is really useful). Java's type system is not sound with respect to arrays either (arrays are covariant, tough they should be invariant), and also not erased, so be careful in those cases, you might not get even a warning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'm just going to have to accept that this is just the way it is. I've suppressed enough warnings with generics to know that it's usually better to be given a warning than for the code to not compile, but to allow you to do *this* just seems ridiculous.

Comment: @pbabcdefp check my comment on chrylis answer. And this doesn't explain why it compiles. It explains the behavior at runtime.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you elaborate? Aren't both answers the same? Don't they both just say that it compiles because `T` is treated as `Object` and when you override you are allowed to return a more specific type?

Comment: @pbabcdefp at run time, the `T` will be treat as `Object`. If this were true at compile time, then doing `Integer a = yourInterfaceImpl.foo();` would not compile because `Integer` is not directly assignable from `Object`.

Comment: This answer could be interpreted to mean that generics are ignored for testing override equivalence. This is not the case; override equivalency is usually determined though the full compile time types as present in the source code. Yes, it is also possible to override by erasure, but this is rather limited, dangerous, and only indended for compatibility with non-generic legacy code, which nowadays is quite rare, and therefore represents atypical usage.